# URL Management in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish

I'm using JSF to make a website for a project, and I use subdirectories to manage what users are able to access which pages.

My WAR project is organized as follows:

```
+Web Pages
    +User
        movies.xhtml
    +WEB-INF
        //beans, faces-config, glassfish-web, and web.xml here
    +images
    +resources
        +css
            header.css
    +templates
        header.xhtml
    index.xhtml
    //other views
```

My navigation rules are as follows

```
<navigation-rule> 
<from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id> 
<navigation-case> 
  <from-outcome>movies</from-outcome> 
  <to-view-id>/User/movies.xhtml</to-view-id> 
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case> 
<from-view-id>*</from-view-id>  
  <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <from-outcome>create</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/create.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <from-outcome>help</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/help.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <from-outcome>search</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/search.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

My web.xml servlet-mapping is as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/vd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>vd/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now, I have no problem with the navigation rule that brings me to /User/movies.xhtml. However, once I am in /User/movies.xhtml, JSF cannot find any of my pages (IE. index.xhtml). However, it can still find the template that movies.xhtml uses.

Why can't JSF find where other views are? How should I change my navigation rules so that it can find them?

I'm running on Glassfish v3.1.2.

Comment: Do you have correct form of url servlet mapping in your web.xml?     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: My servlet mapping is 
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/vd/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
Because when I used url-pattern *.xhtml I couldn't get it to recognize the /User/ subdirectory.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. I stopped using navigation cases and uses JSF 2's implicit navigation and everything worked as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is. I stopped using navigation cases and uses JSF 2's implicit navigation and everything worked as it should.